# Building a firewall application

Tags: android, firewall

Currently I am working on application for private corporate client who wanted to hand over android devices to its employees with firewall protection:

I need to implement two major things where I need your guidance:

- Restrict few categories application being downloaded/installed whichever is possible
- Block few websites on browser

I have no clue regarding above two, I just need a guidance from where I need to start as I tried surfing over Internet but didn't get anything.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your should invest time in researching basic concept of mobile devices. Those are personal devices and By Default anybody owning those devices can customize the setting. Unless you modify things at OS level and implement your restrictions at Kernel Level.

There are possibilities you can restrict Application Download based on country but It is an open market you can not restrict user to download one type of application. They can download from it from whatever they want.

For OS Level Programming purpose you need to invest time understanding Ins and Outs of Android OS and how to customized it and make your own build ( if required ).

Some of those are :

[How to Modify Android Kernel](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/111.html)

[Unpacking, Editing, and Re-Packing the images](http://android-dls.com/wiki/index.php?title=HOWTO%3a_Unpack,_Edit,_and_Re-Pack_Boot_Images)

In my opinion this is the best solution to customized your Android Build. If you develop custom application for above task. Chances are Users can delete or uninstall those application.

Some one else can provide a better idea !

Comment: First of all thanks for your reply, but as per client he wanted an app to do it for him and about deleting an application is not possible as logs will be generated on server for all the devices by expected app.

Comment: @Ankit : I think this could be only possible if you make an application always run in background be keep it monitoring the status of other application whether it still exists or not. Otherwise due to user privacy setting he can delete application without notifying server.

Comment: You may need to build one application which can start with OS and over that you can assign permissions to that applciation to do what ever its intended purpose it. From with in that application you can control which icons or application user can run. or Control the browser session etc. But still i have a doubt whether you can control System Process through that or no.

Comment: I have already implemented app which start on OS reboot using broadcast receiver and runs in background using background service but how to control browser sessions and restrict user for downloading restricted category app from Market.

Comment: http://www.x3watch.com/ This company is doing something similar to what you are trying to implement. Might be something like Spy++ you could detect browser control and underlying pages which are currently being opened. Android is using Firefox i think as their default browser . But there is a chance user can also download other browsers. So here instead of monitoring browser you might need to moinotr incoming traffic.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439101/how-can-i-monitor-and-block-traffic-using-a-filter-list-of-urls